# Recursive quickSort method currently not working as intended

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, recursion, quicksort

I have designed a recursive quickSort method that seems to work for some inputted arrays, but often has slight errors in most cases.

My code is as follows:

```
public class QuickSort {

    public static void quickSort(int[] s) {
        quickSortSub(s, 0, s.length - 1);
    }

    private static void quickSortSub(int[] s, int a, int b) {
        if(b-a > 1) {
            int point = partition(s, a, b);
            quickSortSub(s, a, point - 1);
            quickSortSub(s, point + 1, b);
        } 
    }

    private static int partition(int[] s, int a, int b) {
        int pivot = s[b];
        int left = a;
        int right = b-1;
        while(left < right) {
            while(s[left] < pivot) {
                left++;
            }
            while(s[right] > pivot) {
                right--;
            }
            if(left < right) {
                int tmp = s[left];
                s[left] = s[right];
                s[right] = tmp;
            }
        }
        s[b] = s[left];
        s[left] = pivot;
        return left;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = {85, 10, 24, 63, 45, 27, 100, 31, 96, 50, 40, 23, 49, 96, 120, 105, 13, 5, 42, 69, 22, 12};
        quickSort(arr);
        for (int i: arr) System.out.print(i + ", ");
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

When executed, the 'sorted' list outputs as follows:
5, 10, 12, 22, 13, 23, 24, 31, 27, 40, 42, 45, 49, 50, 63, 69, 85, 96, 96, 100, 120, 105

which is (by inspection) not correct

Answer (score 0):

```java
public class QuickSort {

    public static void quickSort(int[] s) {
        quickSortSub(s, 0, s.length - 1);
    }

    private static void quickSortSub(int[] s, int a, int b) {
        if(b-a >= 1) {//here
            int point = partition(s, a, b);
            if(point>=a+2) //here
            quickSortSub(s, a, point - 1);
            quickSortSub(s, point + 1, b);
        }
    }

    private static int partition(int[] s, int a, int b) {
        int pivot = s[b];
        int left = a;
        int right = b-1;
        while(left < right && right>a) { //here
            while(s[left] < pivot ) {
                left++;
            }
            while(s[right] > pivot) {
                right--;
            }
            if(left < right) {
                int tmp = s[left];
                s[left] = s[right];
                s[right] = tmp;
            }
        }
        //here
        if(s[left] >= pivot ){
            s[b] = s[left];
        s[left] = pivot;
        }

        return left;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = {85, 10, 24, 63, 45, 27, 100, 31, 96, 50, 40, 23, 49, 96, 120, 105, 13, 5, 42, 69, 22, 12};
        quickSort(arr);
        for (int i: arr) System.out.print(i + ", ");
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Comment: This code works properly for that given list, but for larger lists I tried, it started throwing an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: It also stops working on arrays with several duplicates. It appears to catch itself in a loop.